# shellcheck warns about loops over find output even when given the path to begin search

Tags: bash, find, shellcheck

Ubuntu 16.04

```
#!/bin/bash

site="hello"
wDir="/home/websites/${site}/httpdocs/"

for file in $(find "${wDir}" -name "*.css")
do
   echo "$file";
done
exit 0;
```

shellcheck warns me even if I define the start directory but the script works just fine.

```
root@me /scripts/ # shellcheck test.sh

In test.sh line 6:
for file in $(find "${wDir}" -name "*.css")
            ^-- SC2044: For loops over find output are fragile. Use find -exec or a while read loop.
```

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-AbramsIt doesn't but I did not consider shellcheck was warning about files with spaces. It did not click at the time mate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a `for` loop over `find` output is an anti-pattern at best. See [BashFAQ/001 - How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for reason why. Use a `while` loop as below with a `read` command. The below command delimits the output of `find` with a NULL byte and `read` command reads by splitting on that byte, so that all files with special characters in their names are safely handled (including newlines)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

site="hello"
wDir="/home/websites/${site}/httpdocs/"

find "${wDir}" -name "*.css" -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    printf '%s\n' "$file"
done
```

Or altogether avoid using the pipe-lines and do process-substitution

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    printf '%s\n' "$file"
done< <(find "${wDir}" -name "*.css" -type f -print0)
```

The web [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) does not report any issues for either of the two snippets above.

Comment: imo, `| while` is anti pattern too.. `find` already has `-exec` which handles filenames properly...

Comment: @Sundeep, sometimes `-exec` isn't useful. Consider the case where you're modifying shell variables (though, granted, that would be `while ... done < <(find ...)` if you want the updated variables to persist and aren't using ksh or the `lastpipe` option), or calling builtins or shell functions (where `-exec` tells `find` to start a bunch of new shells, when you could otherwise use just one instance). `-exec` is a good tool to use when it's appropriate, but "when it's appropriate" is a constrained set.

Comment: good point.. and `-exec sh/bash/zsh/etc -c` is an option too when shell is needed.. I can only think of parallel processing as a reason for piping find's output..

Comment: Note that [`echo "$file"` is another anti-pattern](/q/65803)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Done Stephane! Appreciate it

Comment: @Sundeep, variables set in `-exec sh -c '...'` don't persist after the `find` command exits, whereas if you put your `find` in a process substitution, you can populate data structures from a `while read` loop. Consider for example: `declare -A exts=( ); while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do [[ $filename = *.* ]] || continue; (( exts[${filename##*.}]+= 1 )); done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0); declare -p exts` as something you couldn't do (with the `exts` variable surviving, and supporting more files than fit on one command line) with `-exec`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yup agree.. I meant that it is an additional option for cases that could be covered with that option..

Answer (score 12):

The problem is exactly what shellcheck is telling you: `for` loops iterating over the output of `find` or similar commands are fragile. For example:

```
$ ls
'a file with spaces' 

$ for file in $(find . ); do    echo "$file"; done
.
./a
file
with
spaces
```

The safe way would be either to use the `-exec` of `find`:

```
$ find . -exec echo  {} \;
.
./a file with spaces
```

Or to use a `while` loop:

```
$ find . -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do echo "$file"; done
.
./a file with spaces
```

Comment: If your shell supports it, you could also do `for file in **/*` or similar.